# $|A|\le|B|<|C| \implies |A|<|C|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I mathematically prove that if $|A|\le|B|<|C| \implies |A|<|C|$?
I tried to prove by negatively assuming that there is a bijection function from A to C but I got stacked.

Comment: You have injections $A\to B$ and $B\to C$. You readily find an injection $A\to C$. And if you assume you have an injection $C\to A$, you readily obtain an injection $C\to B$, contradicting the given.

Comment: Yes, I know that but how can I prove that |A|<|C|? I need to prove that there is no bijection f from A to C.. or injection from C to A  but how

Comment: Hagen just told you: you prove there is an injection, and you prove there is no injection $C\to A$; if there were a bijection $A\to C$, then there would be an injection $C\to A$.

Comment: yes I got that, I was just looking for another way of proving. However, thanks a lot..  Hegan and Arturo